# How to Setup a Push Notification(or GCM) mechanism in android while Back-end uses ASP.NET

Tags: android, asp.net, google-cloud-messaging

How to Setup a Push Notification(or GCM) mechanism in android while Back-end uses ASP.NET

i want setup an application GCM but backend has in ASP.net please refer a Complete Guidelines if could.

Both server side and android side

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question in part, the server side could be implemented in C#. The message format and general approach is documented at the following links.

http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/server.html

https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/http.html

https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/server-ref#table1

That being said, the actual push message can be sent as follows.

```
var iReq = WebRequest.Create("https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send");
iReq.Method = "post";
iReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8";
iReq.Headers.Add(String.Format("Authorization: key={0}", Key));

string iMsg;

// iMsg must be filled with the actual data to be sent
// and understood by the client

var PostData = Uri.EscapeUriString(PostData);

var byteArr = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(PostData);
iReq.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

var DataStream = iReq.GetRequestStream();
DataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
DataStream.Close();

string ServerResponse;  // will contain the response to examine
HttpStatusCode StatusCode;

using (var iRes = iReq.GetResponse())
{
    using (var iReader = new StreamReader(iRes.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        ServerResponse = iReader.ReadToEnd();
    }
    StatusCode = (iResponse as HttpWebResponse).StatusCode;
}
```